# Copy Current Webpage Into a New Window

Tags: javascript, printing

I need to be able to copy the current webpage into a new popup window for a print preview.  There is a grid on the page with children, so if they expand one of the rows to see the child rows, I need to show this in the new window.

Is this possible?

I currently have the popup window open up the same page, but all none of the rows are expanded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps this does the trick (in IE and Firefox, not in Opera. Don't know about WebKit):

```
var yourDOCTYPE = "<!DOCTYPE html..."; // your doctype declaration
var printPreview = window.open('about:blank', 'print_preview');
var printDocument = printPreview.document;
printDocument.open();
printDocument.write(yourDOCTYPE+
           "<html>"+
               document.documentElement.innerHTML+
           "</html>");
printDocument.close();
```

(Note the difference between `window.open()` and `document.open()`!)

However, you will lose all custom DOM thingies, like event handlers and so on. Nonetheless, it might work if you just want to copy 'n paste your HTML.

Comment: I tried this (with jQuery) ... but since expanding the rows is done asynchronously, the new page is not picking up the html.

Comment: I created a JSFiddle, that works at least in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/boldewyn/bbPLp/

Answer (score 0):

Encode the state of open/closed rows into a query string format (like "open=row1+row5+row10") and pass this string in an url to a newly opened window (like "host.com/blah.html?open=row1+row5+row10"). On the target page, in the onload function examine the location object and expand these rows once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JavaScript to access the pop-up window and call functions like "hideRow(x)". I'll add a better example when I get home (iPod touch is no fun to type code on)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just hiding/showing your rows with display:none;? How are you loading up the popup page? If you're reloading the page again, you could use AJAX to pass a dataset to the target page.

Assign a unique ID to each row, and for each row that is expanded, add the row's ID into an array. Pass that array or object as a data member via AJAX when your print preview function is called, then expand the applicable rows in your onsuccess callback function after the page is loaded.