# How to copy content of iframe into popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript-framework

Is there any way to copy iframe's content into popup window in jQuery?

```
$(popUpWindow.document).append($('#iframe1').contents());
$(popUpWindow.document).append($('#iframe1').contents().find('body').html());
```

All of them are not working!

Thanks

Comment: Is the iFrame pointing to a page on the same domain? You may be running in to cross-domain security. Also, if you're going for the whole page, what's wrong with popup.location = iframe.location?

Comment: @Bard ... In fact, iFrame is not pointing to any external page, it is just a hidden iFrame where we normally store a html page.

Comment: You may find this answer on [copying the dom to a new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155122/copy-current-webpage-into-a-new-window) helpful.

Comment: @Nicholas ... in fact, my trouble is getting the content from iFrame

Comment: it might be easier to have the html content inside a hidden <div> instead of an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If all that you need to do is actually obtain the iframe contents, you can try something a bit more low level than jquery: raw javascript!

```
var getIframeContent = function (id) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    return iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

But I would imagine something similar is going on underneath the hood in JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention which popup you are using and by content what do you mean.

Example for jquery-ui popup (dialog)

HTML:

```
<div id="myDialog" >
  <p>default dialog</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#myDialog" ).dialog();
    $( "#myDialog p" ).html($("iframe").contents().find("body").html());
});
```