# How to open a popup window having the source code of a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a file - **filedata.php**. The file shows only a `CLICK ME` link when opened in the browser. On clicking the `CLICK ME` link a popup window should appear which has the source code of **filedata.php**. I wrote the following code but it isn't working (no pop-up window appears). Please help me to figure out the error.

SCRIPT -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a.xy").click(function (event) {
        //Prevent default behavior
        event.preventDefault();
        var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($php_array) ?>;
        var disp = window.open('','','width=400,height=400');
        $(disp.document.body).text( js_array.join("\n") );
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP CODE -

```
<?php
// Get a file into an array.
echo '<a href="" class="xy" onclick="openWin()">CLICK ME!</a><br>';
$path='C:\wamp\www\directory_listing\filedata.php';
$lines = file($path);

// Loop through our array, show HTML source as HTML source; and line numbers too.
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $php_array[$line_num]="Line <b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />";
}

$html = implode('', file($path));
$trimmed = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Source means PHP source?

Comment: It means full source (Anything written in filedata.php)

Comment: onclick="openWin()" this means the click call a function: function openwin(){ //code } is missing from js use firebug. you will see the error in console

Comment: @Catalin >> I removed it, the error is actually with json_encode. The console says - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: so you need a popup window that contains filedata.php ?

Comment: I need a popup window that contains source code of filedata.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your hava used the wrong way to append html code, change `$(disp.document.body).text( js_array.join("\n") );` to `disp.document.body.innerHTML = js_array.join("\n");`.

Below is all my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
// Get a file into an array.
echo '<a href="" class="xy" onclick="openWin()">CLICK ME!</a><br>';
$path='C:\wamp\www\directory_listing\filedata.php';
$lines = file($path);

// Loop through our array, show HTML source as HTML source; and line numbers too.
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
{
    $php_array[$line_num]="Line <b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />";
}

$html = implode('', file($path));
$trimmed = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a.xy").click(function (event) {
        //Prevent default behavior
        event.preventDefault();
        var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($php_array) ?>;
        var disp = window.open('','','width=400,height=400');
        disp.document.body.innerHTML = js_array.join("\n");
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks @wander. Also, try and catch block can be included for json_encode and the onclick attribute has to be removed from <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to communicate with new window but it is not possible to pass dom to new window.You would basically need to convert the generated DOM to a string, pass it across to the new window and then parse it as though it was a document.

**[Like This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155122/copy-current-webpage-into-a-new-window)**